# One-Parameter Families of Indecomposable Representations of the Preprojective Algebra of type A5

Tags: rt.representation-theory, preprojective-algebra

Consider the preprojective algebra of type $A_n$.  It is well known that this algebra is of finite representation type when $n<5$, of tame representation type when $n=5$, and of wild representation type when $n>5$.  In particular, this means that there exists a family of indecomposable representations of the preprojective algebra of type $A_5$ which depends on a continuous parameter.  I was wondering if anyone knew of an explicit example of such a family.  Any examples of two-parameter families in type $A_n$ for $n>5$ would be also helpful.

Comment: I decided to add a tag to bump this since I specifically would like to see a proof that the A_6 preprojective algebra is of wild representation type.

Comment: And a two-parameter A6 example has been given at mathoverflow.net/questions/202259 by Jeremy Rickard. (I wonder what happened to the tag I apparenly added - I'll try again)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I only know the answer for type A5.
The smallest dimension-vector for a one-parameter family of indecomposable representations is (1, 2, 2, 2, 1). All the representations in the family have socle and head both equal to S_2 \oplus S_4. (Here S_i is the one-dimensional representation attached to vertex i, with the standard labelling of the vertices.) With these informations, you will easily construct the desired representations.
The paper *Semicanonical bases and preprojective algebras* by Geiss, Leclerc and Schröer (Ann. Sci. Ecole Norm. Sup. 38 (2005), 193-253) contains a precise description of the representations of the preprojective algebra of type A5.

Comment: It's probably useful to add the location for a free download of the 2005 paper: http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=ASENS_2005_4_38_2_193_0.